# Sign of algebraic numbers

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I have a bivariate polynomial `p` and would like to find its sign when evaluated over two algebraic numbers. The numbers are in so-called "isolating interval representation", i.e. defined by a square-free univariate polynomial `q` and two rational end-points. The coefficients of all the polynomials are integers.

If I understood correctly, to compute the sign of an univariate polynomial one needs to find the "pseudo-remainder sequence" of `p` and `q`, evaluate the sequence twice (over each of the end-points) and count the number of times the signs changed (correct?).

**But how to proceed in the case of bivariate polynomial, i.e. how to compute "PRS" of biviariate and univariate polynomial?**